# Do capacitors go bad more quickly in an electronic game console if it is left in the cupboard for years or decades without play VS playing regularly?

Tags: capacitor

Do capacitors go bad more quickly in an electronic game console if it is left in the cupboard for years or decades without play or do they go bad more quickly when playing regularly?

Is there any scientific research to support your answer?

Comment: Heat tends to kill capacitors, so I would expect that being powered off is better.

Comment: Thanks @user1850479

Comment: Some links about dielectric degradation: [Kemet](https://www.kemet.com/en/us/technical-resources/aluminum-electrolytics-and-applied-power.html) and [TDK](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjDs5jU3tf9AhVok2oFHXOWBckQFnoECDcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tdk-electronics.tdk.com%2Fdownload%2F185386%2F5f33d2619fa73419e2a4af562122e90c%2Fpdf-generaltechnicalinformation.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1simyl0ct4FoLOvmmuEoG9). Bottom line, it's best to power your devices periodically to reform the aluminum electrolytic capacitors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do capacitors go bad more quickly ... if ... left [unused] for years ...?"

Some capacitors, yes.

Electrolytic capacitors will degrade whether used, or unused, but at least some, if not the majority, will last longer if there is *some* (steady) voltage applied to them. They can sometimes be "rejuvenated" by applying a steady voltage to them over a period of time, which will rebuild the dielectric layer.

2 years seems to be a commonly agreed upon lower limit to the shelf-life of aluminum electrolytic capacitors. Some capacitors will have a longer shelf life, but unless you know better (for example from a datasheet), you shouldn't assume a longer shelf life. (As Hearth points out, in comments below, electronics stored in a hot attic, or in high humidity may have an even shorter shelf life.)

Intermittent use will probably optimize the longevity of aluminum electrolytic capacitors.

Ceramic, polymer, mica etc. dielectrics are unlikely to degrade much over time, although various polymers films likely to degrade faster at warmer temperatures, which are more likely to occur in active use, than on the shelf.

Depending upon environmental conditions, the encapsulating plastic (often epoxy?) of a capacitor will degrade, although this will rarely cause electrical degradation. The environment should not be too moist, nor too dry, nor too hot, nor too cold. Since operating electronics tend to be hotter than electronics on the shelf, I would expect the encapsulating material to fair better without use than with use.

Comment: Elevated temperatures are more likely to occur in active use than on the shelf, except when the shelf is in an attic. Being left in an attic for years can easily destroy electronics; batteries and electrolytic capacitors are particularly susceptible.

Comment: @Hearth there are many online sources that list 2 years for the shelf-life of aluminum electrolytics. I have used devices with aluminum electrolytics actively for many more years than 2. In some cases, the heat from active use will cause damage faster than the electrolyte eats through the oxide/dielectric layer from inactive use. In other cases, the reverse will be true.

Comment: Yes, but having lived in subtropical areas, I can tell you that attics get *hot*, especially in the summer. I doubt the 2-year shelf life applies at 95% relative humidity and 50 to 60 °C.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for all the knowledge!